# Using Apache Camel and Restlet to get an API

Tags: xml, maven, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I’m doing a very simple Fuse integration application that takes a XML from an API website (data portal from Stockholms Stad). I’m using Apache Camel to route “from” 
the API url in “to” a new word doc file. The 2 files I have here are the Spring XML `camel.context.xml`file and the `pom.xml` for the dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <camelContext id="camel-fuse-api" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="api2fuse">
            <!-- Input from Rest API -->
            <!-- Process the XML from the Rest API -->
            <!-- Output to a text file (TESTING the route) -->
            <from id="_from1" uri="restlet:http:80://data.stockholm.se/set/Befolkning/Befforandr/?apikey=<api-key>?restletMethod=GET"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="file://C:/<localfile>?fileName=test_new_xml.txt"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="XML was copied to the local folder in a .txt file"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
    <bean class="org.restlet.Component" id="RestletComponent"/>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent" id="RestletComponentService">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <ref bean="RestletComponent"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cgi.fuse</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Fuse API</name>
  <description>Fuse integration for API</description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <properties>
    <camel.version>2.17.0.redhat-630187</camel.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <version.maven-bundle-plugin>2.1.0</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>6.3.0.redhat-187</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <restlet.version>2.1.7</restlet.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
      <version>5.11.0.redhat-630187</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0.redhat-630187</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>  
   <id>maven-restlet</id>  
   <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>  
   <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>  
</repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>Fuse</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>Empty Camel Spring Example [Fuse]</Bundle-Name>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <fileApplicationContextUri>src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml</fileApplicationContextUri>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I’m running the project on “jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187” Runtime Server on JBoss Developer Studio 10.1.0 GA. I start the server but no file is created. It’s not functioning and I assume it’s some wrong syntax in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from a timer if you want to call an external existing REST service.

```
from timer
   to restlet
   to file
```

What you do with

```
from restlet
```

is intended if you host a new REST service yourself.

And with the timer you need to find out how frequently you want to call that existing REST service. The timer has options you can configure for that.

Comment: Oh, I see. So what I understand is that calling an external REST web service requires a timer to begin a connection, sort of listening or polling correct?

Comment: Yeah if you are using Camel routes. If you want to call any Camel endpoint from Java code you can use ProducerTemplate (as a client api). However Camel routes are very often used with Camel

Comment: The ProducerTemplate documentation says it allows message exchanges between endpoints. I'm new to the concept of messaging. Does it mean that, if I write the Java code I will have to implement a message exchange between the API I'm calling and my localhost endpoint? Is this needed so that I can generate the new word doc file I want?

Comment: Instead of the timer you can use direct endpoint which you can call once from Java code using a ProducerTemplate. Then you can use the route to call rest and save as a file. It depends what you want to do. eg ask the question - what triggers the download of this file? Is it something from Java code or should it be scheduled and run automatic in the background etc.

Comment: Yeah I still need to think about the requirements of my project to see if it scheduled or run automatic. But your insights were really helpful. Also, I'm learning a lot from Camel in Action. Thanks Claus.